# All possible combinations of object's key and value pairs with recursion in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion, combinations

Here is what I wrote: (key in the headline is prop here)

```
var data = {
    dup_by: ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3'],
    prop1: ['val11', 'val12'],
    prop2: ['val21', 'val22'],
    prop3: ['val31', 'val32', 'val33'],
    test_obj: {},
    test_obj_arr: []
};

var dupRecursion = function(prop_index) {
      let prop_name = data.dup_by[prop_index]
      data[prop_name].forEach((value) => {
        data.test_obj[prop_name] = value
        console.log(prop_name)
        console.log(value)
        console.log(data.test_obj)
        if (prop_index == 0) {
          data.test_obj_arr = [data.test_obj, ...data.test_obj_arr]
          console.log(data.test_obj_arr)
        } else {
          dupRecursion(prop_index - 1)
        }
      })
      return;
    };

dupRecursion(data.dup_by.length - 1)
```

Here is the expected result:

```
data.test_obj_arr = [{prop1: 'val11', prop2: 'val21', prop3: 'val31'},
{prop1: 'val11', prop2: 'val21', prop3: 'val32'},
{prop1: 'val11', prop2: 'val21', prop3: 'val33'},
{prop1: 'val11', prop2: 'val22', prop3: 'val31'},
{prop1: 'val11', prop2: 'val22', prop3: 'val32'},
{prop1: 'val11', prop2: 'val22', prop3: 'val33'},
{prop1: 'val12', prop2: 'val21', prop3: 'val31'},
{prop1: 'val12', prop2: 'val21', prop3: 'val32'},
{prop1: 'val12', prop2: 'val21', prop3: 'val33'},
{prop1: 'val12', prop2: 'val22', prop3: 'val31'},
{prop1: 'val12', prop2: 'val22', prop3: 'val32'},
{prop1: 'val12', prop2: 'val22', prop3: 'val33'}]
```

There are some solutions for combinations of arrays instead of objects vals and props.

I've tried some changes in order but they all result in the same output:

```
data.test_obj_arr = [{prop1: 'val12', prop2: 'val22', prop3: 'val33'},
{prop1: 'val12', prop2: 'val22', prop3: 'val33'},
{prop1: 'val12', prop2: 'val22', prop3: 'val33'},
{prop1: 'val12', prop2: 'val22', prop3: 'val33'},
{prop1: 'val12', prop2: 'val22', prop3: 'val33'},
{prop1: 'val12', prop2: 'val22', prop3: 'val33'},
{prop1: 'val12', prop2: 'val22', prop3: 'val33'},
{prop1: 'val12', prop2: 'val22', prop3: 'val33'},
{prop1: 'val12', prop2: 'val22', prop3: 'val33'},
{prop1: 'val12', prop2: 'val22', prop3: 'val33'},
{prop1: 'val12', prop2: 'val22', prop3: 'val33'},
{prop1: 'val12', prop2: 'val22', prop3: 'val33'}]
```

Since the logs are coming out as expected:

```
console.log(prop_name)
console.log(value)
```

But these aren't:

```
console.log(data.test_obj)
console.log(data.test_obj_arr)
```

I believe that the problem is in the assignment:

```
data.test_obj[prop_name] = value
```

Singularly it works, just not inside the recursion. Tried to use Object.Assign and it didn't work either.

All those functions, as much as I'm informed, are synced functions.

What am I missing?

Comment: This is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: @ScottHunter sorry, edited.

Answer (score 0):

Create a 2D array of of each `prop_x` values. Then create a create a [Cartesian product](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57597533/3082296) of the array. Loop through the combinations and create an object for each combination with `dup_by` as keys

```js
const input = {
    dup_by: ["prop1", "prop2", "prop3"],
    prop1: ["val11", "val12"],
    prop2: ["val21", "val22"],
    prop3: ["val31", "val32", "val33"],
    test_obj: {},
    test_obj_arr: [],
}

const keys = input.dup_by,
      matrix = keys.map(k => input[k])

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/57597533/3082296
const combos = matrix.reduce((acc, curr, i) =>
  acc.flatMap(c => curr.map(n => [].concat(c, n)))
)

const createObject = (values) =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    keys.map((k, i) => [k, values[i]])
  )

const output = combos.map(createObject)

console.log("matrix: ", JSON.stringify(matrix))
console.log("combos: ", JSON.stringify(combos))
console.log(output)
```

If [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) is not supported, you can use `reduce` to create an object from an array of keys and values

```
const createObject = (values) =>
  keys.reduce((acc, k, i) => (acc[k] = values[i], acc), {})
```